# Post log parsing by logstash, there are no fields produced

Tags: logstash, kibana, logstash-grok

As similar questions have been repeated, i've taken care to look at previous answers and unfortunately it has not solved my issue.

With the below mentioned filter configuration of the logstash, I'm expecting the fields thread, log level and message to be generated after parsing the log.

I've tried this filter on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ and the output generates the fields as mentioned in the filters.

However apart from the message, there are no fields which are being shown on output JSON/Kibana. There are no error while parsing.

Would be helpful if anyone can point out the mistake here. Thanks!

**Filter Config**

```
filter {
  if [type] == "reporting" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "\[(?<timestamp>%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601})\] - %{NOTSPACE:thread} - %{LOGLEVEL:loglevel} (?<logger>[A-Za-z0-9$_.]+) - %{GREEDYDATA:message}$"}
    }
  }
}
```

**Log Example**

```
[2016-08-15 09:44:36,858] - RServer - INFO transformation - [01] starting the process for day 2016-06-06
```

**Generated JSON**

```
 {
  "_index": "filebeat-2016.08.15",
  "_type": "log",
  "_id": "xxx",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "[2016-08-15 09:44:36,858] - RServer - INFO transformation - [01] starting the process for day 2016-06-06",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-15T09:44:37.700Z",
    "source": "/xxx/yyy/main.log",
    "count": 1,
    "fields": {
      "application": "reporting",
      "category": "main"
    },
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "xxx",
      "name": "xxx"
    },
    "offset": 5033597,
    "type": "log",
    "input_type": "log",
    "host": "xxx",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1471254277700
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1471254277700
  ]
}
```

Comment: It does not look like you are setting the type variable, hence your filter is never called. Remove the if, and try again.

Comment: @pandaadb So your comment triggered an idea to check the configuration of the FileBeat (as the if condition in the Logstash was intentional). I found that one of the fields, 'output_type' was missing. I added it and the fields are appearing now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem :) Alternatively, you can in your input do something like type => "reporting" which would set that as well

Comment: @pandaadb I have different categories of logs coming in from the same instance of FileBeat, so got to tag them at the point of source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from @pandaadb, I got the idea to check the configuration of the FileBeat and realised that a field, "output_type" was missing. That meant that the logs coming in were not getting filtered as the filter was expecting a certain type.

With the "output_type", a key word gets added and is used by the filter to parse the logs as per the mentioned GROK expression. Since the same instance of FileBeat is forwarding different categories of logs, it is being tagged at the forwarder itself rather than in the input configuration of the Logstash.